# how to avoid sorting on clustering key columns in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am a bit new to cassandra.
I have created a table like below
**create table events(day text, hour text, sip text, dip text, count, counter,
primary key((day,hour), sip,dip));**

our use case is, application receives many events per second. we would like to have a seprate partition per hour of a day and we need to update the counter if the same event is received again. and also we would like to have unique entries for the combination of dip and sip columns hence I have included those as part of the primary key.

Here as dip, sip columns are forming a clustering key, sorting is taking place while inserting the records into the table. In our case sorting is not required for these columns, sorting is a overhead while we include millions of rows in a table. How to avoid this sorting overhead, Can any one help me?

Comment: Sorting may not be an overhead in this case. To update the counter you will have to do something like 'UPDATE events SET count = count + 1 WHERE day = in_day and hour = in_hour and sip = in_sip and dip = in_dip;' Cassandra would need the records sorted to get to this row quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering by clustering columns is needed for Cassandra to function correctly.  It needs to store the data that way to keep the row keys unique and to support things like range queries on clustering columns.  As Arun says, this allows your subsequent updates to run quickly.

You could reduce the amount of sorting by inserting rows in sorted order, for example by having the first clustering column be a time stamp.  But then you'd lose the benefit of being able to increment your counter since you wouldn't know the time stamp key of the earlier event.  To get the final counts you'd need to do a roll up operation after each hour to aggregate matching events.

Another way would be to make sip and/or dip part of your partition key.  Each event would then hash to a different partition bucket and no sorting would be required.  But then you'd lose the grouping of events into one hour partitions.  This could be good or bad depending on your needs.  If you have a very high rate of events, grouping them all into the same one hour partition could create hot spots since all events will hash to the same node, so making events separate partitions would spread out the write load.  If reading the events later as a one hour chunk is more important to you, then having them grouped into one partition will make reading them more efficient at the cost of more expensive writes due to the sorting.

So in general, if you keep your partitions to a reasonable size, the sorting overhead should not be too large since it is done in memory.  If your partitions are so large that they are causing performance problems, decrease their size by adding another field to the partition key to break the partitions into smaller chunks to spread out the load on more nodes.